# Why is t-BuOK necessary for this synthesis?

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

1-chloro-2-methylpropane --> 2-chloro-2-methylpropane.

My understanding is that an E2 reaction produces two types of alkenes, the major product for non-sterically hindered bases is the more substituted product (Zaitsev) while the major product for sterically hindered bases is the least substituted product (Hofmann). In this instance, there is only one beta carbon and thus, one product. Wouldn't sodium ethoxide be a better choice as a reagent then tert-butoxide as tert-butoxide will run into steric hindrance from the orbitals of the surrounding methyl groups?

Reading from Klein, Organic Chemistry as a Second Language, First Semester Topics, 4e, p.242, 11.80

Comment: Ethoxide is not as strong a base as t-BuOK and is a decent nucleophile which will give significant amounts of the substitution product.

Comment: I see it now! Thank you for the help Waylander.